# neo4j how to return two nodes linked by edge

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following nodes link by a edge

```
MATCH (user)-[:CreatesChat]-(chatitems)
```

Node `user` has the property `user.id`
Node `chatitems` has the property `chatitems.id`

I want to recover the user.id and the  chatitems.id

I tried

```
MATCH (user)-[:CreatesChat]-(chatitems)
WITH user as users ,chatitems as chats ORDER BY chatitems.id DESC LIMIT 10
WITH collect(chats) AS chats1
with collect(users) as users1
UNWIND chats1 AS chatid
unwind users1 as userid
return chatid,userid
```

But I get the error

```
users not defined (line 4, column 14 (offset: 158))
"with collect(users) as users1"
              ^
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Why are you collecting things? What's wrong with `RETURN user.id, chatitems.id` after line 1?

Answer (score 3):

Every time you write a `WITH` you are resetting everything you have returned up to that point, so strictly speaking you would fix this error by making your second WITH statement

```
WITH users, collect(chats) as chats1
```

And then you'd have to make your third

```
WITH users, chats1, collect(users) as users1
```

and so on. But this all strikes me as overkill. It sounds like you simply want:

```
MATCH (user)-[:CreatesChat]-(chatitems)
RETURN user.id, chatitems.id
```